# Change background color disabled togglebutton

Tags: c#, wpf, background, togglebutton

I have a toggle button in my Wpf application which is disabled in the code

```
<ToggleButton IsEnabled="False"/>
```

How can i change the `background` of the disabled button.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to stckoverflow.
I'm afraid it's not quite clear what you're trying to accomplish.
Do you want to disable a toggle button in WPF?

Comment: Hi Timothy thanks for you reply, yes, i have a toggle button in wpf, in the side code, i do isEnabled= false; to the toggle button, but when i do that, the botton turns gray and i need change this to green color.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the background brush of a ToggleButton in the template.

Right click on your Control and -> Edit a copy.

Name it and define where the Style should be (Ressource or local)
There you see a Style and a Template

Sth. like this appear:

```
    <Style x:Key="ToggleButtonStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                    <Themes:ButtonChrome x:Name="Chrome" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" RenderMouseOver="{TemplateBinding IsMouseOver}" RenderPressed="{TemplateBinding IsPressed}" RenderDefaulted="{TemplateBinding Button.IsDefaulted}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                        <ContentPresenter ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding ContentStringFormat}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                    </Themes:ButtonChrome>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                       <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocused" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="RenderDefaulted" TargetName="Chrome" Value="True"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="RenderPressed" TargetName="Chrome" Value="True"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FFADADAD"/>
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="green"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

In the Trigger "IsEnabled" can you set the new Brush directly or via `Binding Value="{StaticResource MyBrush}"`